# Load stored procedure results into data table

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I've been searching the net for answers but have come up empty again and again.

What I'm trying to do:
Load the results from a stored procedure into a DataTable.

What's going wrong:
I'm not getting any rows returned.

Here is my stored proc (SQL Server 2012). It gets the next auto incremented ID of a table you input and returns it.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GET_NEXT_AUTO_ID_OF_TABLE]
    @TABLE_NAME nvarchar(128),
    @NEXT_ID int output
as

declare @latest_id int, @row_count int
    begin 
        set @latest_id = (select IDENT_CURRENT(@TABLE_NAME))
    end
    if @latest_id = 1
    begin
    declare @lRowCountSql nvarchar(1000)
    set @lRowCountSql = N'select @row_count = count(*) from ' + @TABLE_NAME
    exec sp_executesql @lRowCountSql, N'@row_count int out', @row_count out

    if @row_count > 0
        set @next_id = @latest_id + 1
    else
        set @next_id = @latest_id
end
else
    set @next_id = @latest_id + 1
return
```

Is the problem my proc (I'm not good with sql)? When I test the proc in SQL Server I get the result I expect.
But not from my C# code:

```
        List<SqlParameter> aSqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
        aSqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@TABLE_NAME", "your table name") { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar });
        aSqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@NEXT_ID", Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int });
        DataTable lDt = SQLServerUtils.ExecuteStoredProc("GET_NEXT_AUTO_ID_OF_TABLE", aSqlParams);
        int lNextID = lDt.Rows[0].Field<int>("NEXT_ID");

    public static DataTable ExecuteStoredProc(string aProcName, List<SqlParameter> aSqlParams)
    {
        DataTable lResults = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(aProcName, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (aSqlParams != null)
                foreach (SqlParameter lP in aSqlParams)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(lP);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(lResults);
        }
        return lResults;
    }
```

Comment: The whole reason for this elaborate way to get the next ID is because if the table is empty IDENT_CURRENT is 1, but if there is one row IDENT_CURRENT is also 1. So if I use IDENT_CURRENT +1 for an empty table it will mean that next_id is 2 - which it obviously isn't.

Answer (score 0):

An output parameter is returned by itself, not included in a datatable.
I think you need a different procedure that executes these kind of query,

```
public static int ExecuteOutputIntParam(string aProcName, string outputParamName, List<SqlParameter> aSqlParams)
{
    int outValue = -1;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(aProcName, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (aSqlParams != null)
            foreach (SqlParameter lP in aSqlParams)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(lP);

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (aSqlParams != null)
        {
            outValue = Convert.ToInt32(aSqlParams[outputParamName].Value);

        } 
    }
    return outValue;
}
```

**EDIT**
I have copy/pasted your example and I haven't noticed that you rely on the SqlDataAdapter to open/close the connection. In my example the connection should be explicitly opened

Comment: Thanks for the effort but no cigar. 'int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();' gives -1

Comment: OK, but the parameter value?

Comment: Also, I am not sure that you can use this syntax in the storeprocedure `set @latest_id = (select IDENT_CURRENT(@TABLE_NAME))
` A parameter cannot be used to replace a tablename or a fieldname without using a dynamic sql as you do later

Comment: I changed the outValue = to 'outValue = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters[outputParamName].Value);' but it is null

Comment: Hmm, ok. If I execute the proc in SQL Server Management Studio it runs as expected. But I'll change that bit to dynamic sql and see what I get. However, I will only be able to do it tomorrow. Until then.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is that the value I want comes back inside the out parameter.
The fixed code looks like this...

SQL proc:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GET_NEXT_AUTO_ID_OF_TABLE]
    @TABLE_NAME nvarchar(128),
    @NEXT_ID int output
as

declare @latest_id int, @row_count int
begin 
    set @latest_id = (select IDENT_CURRENT(''+@TABLE_NAME+''))
end
if @latest_id = 1
    begin
        declare @lRowCountSql nvarchar(1000)
        set @lRowCountSql = N'select @row_count = count(*) from ' + @TABLE_NAME
        exec sp_executesql @lRowCountSql, N'@row_count int out', @row_count out

        if @row_count > 0
            set @next_id = @latest_id + 1
        else
            set @next_id = @latest_id
    end
else
    set @next_id = @latest_id + 1
return
```

C#:

```
    public static int GetNextIdOfTable(string aTableName)
    {
        int lNextID = 0;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GET_NEXT_AUTO_ID_OF_TABLE", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TABLE_NAME", aTableName) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@NEXT_ID", Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int });

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (cmd.Parameters["@NEXT_ID"] != null && cmd.Parameters["@NEXT_ID"].Value != DBNull.Value)
                return int.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@NEXT_ID"].Value.ToString());
        }
        return lNextID;
    }
```